# python not allowing same value in list

Tags: python, list

i've a python script to parse a grammar. initial code is:

```
num_pro=int(raw_input())

right=[];left=[];

for i in range(num_pro):
  map(list.append, (left, right), raw_input().split('->'))

right_edit=[];left_edit=[];i=0

for rhs in right:
  parts=rhs.split('|')
  for each in parts:
    left_edit.append(left[i])
    right_edit.append(each)
  i+=1

for each in right_edit:
  print left_edit[right_edit.index(each)]+" -> "+each
```

i'm taking input from a file which contains:

```
6
E->TZ
Z->+TZ|e
T->FY
Y->*FY|e
F->(E)|a
X->*ZX|e
```

the output comes as:

```
E -> TZ
Z -> +TZ
Z -> e
T -> FY
Y -> *FY
Z -> e    #unexpected
F -> (E)
F -> a
X -> *ZX
Z -> e    #unexpected
```

while the expected output is:

```
E -> TZ
Z -> +TZ
Z -> e
T -> FY
Y -> *FY
Y -> e    #expected
F -> (E)
F -> a
X -> *ZX
X -> e    #expected
```

i've searched and found that with dictionaries same key is not allowed and in set also same values are not allowed. in my code i'm not using dictionaries or sets. also i'm not using `list.index(value)`. still why such output is coming. how to get the expected output.

Comment: What do you mean by "i'm not using list.index(value)"? You most certainly are, and in fact it is what's causing the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing to do with `dict`. Your list actually contains what is expected.

The culprit is the output print statement:

```
print left_edit[right_edit.index(each)]+" -> "+each
```

`right_edit.index(each)` will find the first element. Since you got multiple `e`s it will always find the first one and map that to `Z`.

Use something like:

```
for l, r in zip(left_edit, right_edit):
  print l, "->", r
```

Or:

```
for i, r in enumerate(right_edit):
  print left_edit[i], "->", r
```

Or even better, settle for a better data structure instead of two distinct lists. A simple, single list of two-tuples comes to mind, so basically what `zip()` produces in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest refactoring your code a bit. Instead of using two lists side by side I suggest using tuples inside a list:

Instead of

```
left.append(1)
right.append('a')
```

you would do

```
edit.append((1,'a'))
```

The same goes for your pipe arguments, they should go in a list in the second tuple element:

```
edit.append(('Z', ['+TZ','e']))
```

The code would then look like this:

```
num_pro=int(raw_input())

command=[];

for i in range(num_pro):
  command.append(raw_input().split('->'))    # command is a list of tuples,
                                             # split by '->'

edit=[];

for cmd in command:
  parts = cmd[1].split('|')
  edit.append((cmd[0], parts))          # edit is a list of tuples, the first one
                                        # being the keyword before the '->',
                                        # the second one being a list of all
                                        # arguments, split by |

print(edit)

# now printing is simply a matter of two nested fors

for each in edit:
  for item in each[1]:
    print each[0]+" -> "+item
```

this shows the following output:

```
[('E', ['TZ']), ('Z', ['+TZ', 'e']), ('T', ['FY']), 
 ('Y', ['*FY', 'e']), ('F', ['(E)', 'a']),
 ('X', ['*ZX', 'e'])]

E -> TZ
Z -> +TZ
Z -> e
T -> FY
Y -> *FY
Y -> e
F -> (E)
F -> a
X -> *ZX
X -> e
```